# pip install - NameError:name __main__ is not defined

Tags: python, pip

I'm currently having some trouble installing the `pygments`-package. I tried to run:

```
pip install pygments
```

But, however, I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(__main__._main())
NameError: name '__main__' is not defined
```

What's the problem?

Edit: My pip version is 9.0.3

Comment: what is pip version?

Comment: I edited my post to include this information.

Comment: try upgrading pip version using this command "pip install --upgrade pip"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember exactly what it is, but for me it helped simple `sudo pip install pygments` or `pip3 install pygments`